# Entry value of ComboBox1 to label1

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, label

so, I have this code that writes text to label1. However overwrites the original text, selecting a new value.
As another entry for the previous value? 
label1 should look like this:
one - two - three-...

Thank you

```
    private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        string text;
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "one")
        {
            text = "one";
            label1.Text = " - " + text;
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "two")
        {
            text = "two";
            label1.Text = " - " + text;
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "three")
        {
            text = "three";
            label1.Text = " - " + text;
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
label1.Text = label1.Text + " - " + text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assiging new value every time, to append text you have to do something like this:

```
label1.Text += " - " + text;
```

Comment: Both these are answers are correct and equivalent, although I would say this is the preferred way.